# twice I married a French woman

Tags: meaning, adverbs, ambiguity, numbers

a. Twice, I almost married a French woman.

b. I almost married a French woman twice.

Do those imply that it was the same woman?

Do those imply that I married a French woman once and almost had a second marriage with the same woman?

Do those imply that I married a French woman once and almost had a second marriage with another French woman?

[Related Word Reference post.](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/twice-i-married-a-french-woman.3775719/)

Comment: It seems you are in the habit of posting here and on WordReference as well. I suggest you link your WR post in your future questions, for context. In general, we don't look favorably upon cross-posting. You are not allowed to crosspost across the SE network. If you have asked outside SE, you could post the same question on ELL, but it is not a good idea if you have received good, illuminating answers on another website. You shouldn't use these platforms to crosscheck each other. This is not a game. If you have asked elsewhere, don't withhold that information. Tell us.

Answer (score 1):

When we say "imply" it means that we can be certain, and in this case we can't be certain.  So it does not imply it is the same woman.

For example:

> I eat an apple everyday.

Does not mean it is the same apple.

The apple example is unambigous.  But your example looks much more ambiguous.  It is possible to have nearly married the same woman on two occasions.  The ambiguity could be used as a set up for a joke, but otherwise you should try to avoid it.

> I almost married the same French woman, twice!

Or just add a clarification:

> I almost married a French woman, twice.  Not the same woman, of course. Two different women, first Marie in Paris in  '94 and then Isabelle in Saigon in 2006.

If you are talking about person that you did marry, you would probably call them by name, not just "a French woman"

> I almost re-married my ex-wife, Monique, in 2006. We'd split up two years earlier, but in Christmas 2005 we had an affair...